# Upload a .textproto file to S3 location

Tags: java, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, protocol-buffers

I'm looking to upload a string into a file (with .textproto extension) to an S3 bucket. How do I upload the string without creating a local file.

I am using the following example method.

```
public static uploadFileToS3(AmazonS3 client, String content) {
    client.putObject(bucketName, key, content);
}
```

The key in the method is the path inside the bucket. This is where I'm also specifying the file I want to store the content in.

Ex: **key="/dir1/dir2/file.textproto"**

I want to store the *content* string inside *file.textproto*. Creating a local *file.textproto* and then uploading to S3 works fine. But, I do not want to create a temporary file.

*content* is a string generated by **TextFormat.printer().printToString(*some protobuf object*)**

Any suggestions on how I can do this will help. Thanks!

Comment: S3 is an object based storage, you can't write to it dynamically. you need to create the file locally and store it on S3. you also can't append to the file directly.

Comment: Instead of giving it a local file, you can pass bytes/string via `putObject()`. Take a look at the [documentation](https://sdk.amazonaws.com/java/api/latest/software/amazon/awssdk/services/s3/S3Client.html) for `putObject()`.

Comment: Thanks for the answers guys. The receiving entity consumes the string from a .textproto file. I guess I'll need to create a local file to upload one.